# Front-end library to intelligently parse "Collection+JSON"

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

"Collection+JSON" is a special format of JSON that is being returned by an API that I want to use. I am looking for a front-end JavaScript library (not an NPM module) that can intelligently parse the standard "Collection+JSON" format. Right now, the data that I want is in the first element of an array in the JSON, but it seems wonky and short-sighted to make that assumption. So I am looking for a library that will find the key value that I am looking for instead writing this myself. There's gotta be something out there, does anyone know what I am talking about?

http://amundsen.com/media-types/collection/format/

I am looking for something like this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/collection-json

but front-end instead of back-end...

Answer (score 1):

The libary you posted supports that:

> Node.js and Browser compatible

[collection-json](https://github.com/CamShaft/collection-json.js)